# Pull and Push image to another project using GCloud container builder

Tags: docker, gcloud

I have 2 gcloud projects, say `foo` and `bar`. And I have a docker image named `gcr.io/foo/cat:latest` in the container registry of `foo` project. Need a way to promote this image to `bar` project while renaming the tag to `gcr.io/bar/cat:1.0.0`. How to do this within the gcloud container service of `bar` project ?

Comment: Give it the tag like you did originally and push it.

Comment: But how to pull from one project and push to another project ? A service account is only there for one project. Can I share a service account between projects ? The container builder runs with cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com account. It doesnt have access to pull from another project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to get it done following this article: https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-single-docker-repository-with-multiple-gke-projects-1672689f780c

Steps:
1. Get the container builder service account ID of the `bar` project from the IAM page. Hint: member name ends with `@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`.
2. Add new IAM member to `foo` project with the service account ID we got earlier and have 'Storage Object Viewer' permissions.

Now the container builder service account of `bar` project can access(pull) container images of `foo` project.

Comment: Make sure the cloud builder API is enabled.